# Delphi FMX: HTTPClient asynchronous Post works in Windows, Fails in Android

Tags: android, delphi, asynchronous, httpclient, firemonkey

I'm using THTTPClient in Delphi 10.3 to perform a POST operation and bring data from a server. Parameters are JSON. Problem is:

- When compiled as a **Win32** application, it works perfectly for both when  performing a asynchronous call or not.
- When compiled as an **Android** app, it fails in the async call and works fine in the normal way.

The failure error indicates that somehow the request is not passing the json parameters (that only happens in async mode). *For example: if the remote server requires to pass two parameters (say, name and age) I'll get the remote error that "name is a mandatory field".*

My code is based on a Delphi download sample.
Is there something I should change for this to work in Android? Thanks!

Here is the relevant code:

```
//the content  of mmoParams.Text is a JSON string:
//{"name":"somebody","salary":"1000","age":"51"}

Params := TStringStream.Create(mmoParams.Text, TEncoding.UTF8);
Params.Position := 0;
// prepare the request
HTTPClient.ContentType := 'application/json';
HTTPClient.Accept      := 'application/json';
if chkAsync.IsChecked then begin
    // prepare the request
    HTTPClient.ContentType := 'application/json';
    HTTPClient.Accept      := 'application/json';
    // make the request and handle in the callback
    HTTPResult:= HTTPClient.BeginPost(DoEndPost,edtURL.Text,Params);
end
else begin
    // make the request
    HTTPResponse       := HTTPClient.Post(edtURL.Text,Params);
    // handle response
    lblStatusCode.Text := HTTPResponse.StatusCode.ToString;
    mmoResult.Text     := HTTPResponse.ContentAsString(TEncoding.UTF8);
end;
```

and here's the callback procedure for when the async call (BeginPost) is made.

```
procedure TMainForm.DoEndPost(const AsyncResult: IAsyncResult);

begin
  try
    HTTPResponse := THTTPClient.EndAsyncHTTP(AsyncResult);
    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      procedure
      begin
          // handle result
         lblStatusCode.Text := HTTPResponse.StatusCode.ToString;
         mmoResult.Text     := HTTPResponse.ContentAsString(TEncoding.UTF8);
      end);
  finally
  end;
end;
```

Comment: "The failure error indicates.." Then where is it? i.e. include it in your question.

Comment: Thanks I'll try to be more clear. But it's an error from the remote server, indicating clearly that you are not passing the required arguments (ex: "you must indicate name of the employee"). As if the json parameters are not being passed to the remote url.

Comment: You're also missing what *exactly* is being passed in mmoParams.Text. Either it's not formatted correctly, or the server is expecting the parameters in the URL, rather than the content.

Comment: Added, @DaveNottage, but the thing is that exactly the same code and parameters work in non async mode.

Comment: Check the documentation for BeginPost. It expects the TStrings parameter to be a string list, i.e. not JSON content. I actually cannot seem to find a way of doing what you want with BeginPost. You might be better off using an Post in an anonymous thread

Comment: oh @DaveNottage there's an overload alternative with a tstream (I'm converting the string into a stream in the code above), it does work in non async mode, but who knows that might a be a problem.  I'm quite unskilled in threads, but I think that might be the answer. Tried with an anonymous thread but also went into trouble. Geez I've tried every HTTPClient alternative.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @DaveNottage, an anonymous thread with standard Post was my best solution so far. This is the function I've been using quite succesfully so far.

I call it from the main program with the destination url, the params that will be sent as JSON and a Callback Procedure that will handle the HTTPResponse received.

```
procedure HTTPPostAsync(HTTPClient: TNetHTTPClient; url, params: string; CallBack: HTTPClientProc);

var
  Thread: TThread;

begin

  // define the thread
  Thread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread (
      procedure
      var
          HTTPResponse: IHTTPResponse;
          JSon        : TStringStream;
      begin
            Json   := TStringStream.Create(Params, TEncoding.UTF8);
            Json.Position := 0;

            HTTPClient.ContentType := 'application/json';
            HTTPClient.Accept      := 'application/json';
            HTTPClient.ConnectionTimeout := 20000;
            HTTPClient.ResponseTimeout   := 20000;
            try
                HTTPResponse:= HTTPClient.Post(url,Json);
                TThread.Synchronize (TThread.CurrentThread,
                    procedure
                    begin
                        Callback(HTTPResponse);
                    end
                );
            finally
                Json.Free;
            end;
      end
  );

  // let it roll
  Thread.start;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy files from {$BDS}/source/rtl/net from 10.2.3 into your project directory and cut non-exist function GetEncodingMIMEName into 'utf-8' everywhere.
This fix works fine, but it will better if Embarcadero will stop make stupid bugs with every release